# How to monitor Windows Server events with Centreon Nagios

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange, windows-event-log, centreon

I want to monitor events on a Windows Exchange Server (Windows 2008 R2) and have installed NSclient ++ so I can use Centreon Nagios to monitor it. I did a bit of research and came across this question that I found somewhat helpful: [How to monitor Windows host with Nagios?](https://serverfault.com/questions/104045/how-to-monitor-windows-host-with-nagios)

Nick Kavadias gave a good answer but it did not provide an explanation on how to configure the Nagios config file in such a way that it would monitor a specific service on the server. So, how do I set up a service in Nagios in such a way that it will detect when a windows event occurs on a server?

Comment: http://www.nsclient.org/nscp/wiki/CheckEventLog/CheckEventLog/old

Comment: You seem to be asking two questions. How do I monitor a specific service and how do I monitor specific events.  Is that correct?

Comment: I personally monitored this using NXLog + Logstash.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the step by step instructions to Monitor `Windows Event` Log With `Nagios`.:

http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/765-monitor-windows-event-log-with-nagios

The above tutorial is for server side setup for services. Instead server side changes, [Check_MK](http://mathias-kettner.de/check_mk.html) agent checks is also the best way to keep monitoring services.

Answer (score 0):

Go to [exchange.nagios.org](http://exchange.nagios.org) It has a lot of plugins you can download and run to scan just about anything. Installation is pretty easy, too--for most of the plugins, you simply copy the downloaded file into /usr/local/nagios/libexec, write your commands.cfg, and restart nagios!

The other option would be to check all windows server event log through a centralized monitoring system for this you can go for any Event log monitoring utility